# MySQL Multiple IF CASE Statements

Tags: mysql

I have a temporary table "productsTmp", in which I have a column "footprintSize". 
The column contains several strings with the next format:

```
a) 12 x 34
b) v 11
c) 12 x 34 (v 12)
```

I want to extract the numbers only, in order to obtain something like:

```
a) v1 = 12 ; v2 = 34
b) v3 = 11
c) v1 = 12 ; v2 = 34 ; v3 = 12
```

Note: The values are from a Rectangular Prism, v1 = width, v2 = length, v3 = height. The height always comes after the character "v" (which in my case is ø).

To extract this values, I thought of using a subquery loop, but I've only come with the next idea:

```
IF footprintSize LIKE '%x%'
   -- Example: 24 x 24
      SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(footprintSize, 'x', 1) AS lval;
      SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(footprintSize, 'x', -1) AS rval;

            -- Example: 8 x 8 (Ø 10)
            IF rval LIKE '%)%'
            SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(footprintSize, '(', -1), ' ', -1), ')', 1) AS dval;

   ELSE
      -- Example: ø 11
      SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(footprintSize, ' ', -1) AS dval;

   END IF;
```

However I've been told that "IF" only works in stored procedures, which is not something I'm looking for. So I tried the next:

```
SELECT
    CASE TRUE
      WHEN footprintSize LIKE "%x%" THEN (SUBSTRING_INDEX(footprintSize,'x', 1))
      WHEN footprintSize LIKE "%)%" THEN (SUBSTRING_INDEX(footprintSize,')', -1))
    END as "footprintSize"
FROM productsTmp
```

But I'm not close to achieve what I want.

At the end, I want to have something like:

```
footprintSize     lval     rval     dval
24 x 24            24       24
8 x 8 (Ø 10)        8       8        10
ø 11                                 11
```

For the empty spaces, I can have null or even add a zero, but I'm more concerned of how can I split this data into three columns.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you not just store the data correctly to begin with?

Comment: I do understand it is horrible, but that's the way I receive the data :(

Comment: If it was me, I think I would try to construct some kind of parser (in PHP, say) that took the raw data and cleaned it up prior to submission to the database. MySQL has no preg_match capability, making this task really tough.